# isset($_POST[' '])) not working for data variable when ajax is used

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have commentdb.php file where button of class `.like-btn` is created and has script.js file linked to it
and have another db.php file where `isset($_POST['key'])` is used.

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.like-btn').click(function(){

    var post_id = $(this).data('id');
        alert(post_id);
    $clicked_btn = $(this);

    var act = "";

    if ($clicked_btn.hasClass('fa-thumbs-o-up')) {
        act = 'like';
    } else if ($clicked_btn.hasClass('fa-thumbs-up')) {
        act = 'unlike';
    }
    // console.log(act);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'db.php',
        data: {
            'key': 1,
            'action': act, 
            'post_id': post_id
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(1);
            // res = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(act);
            if (act == 'like') {
                $clicked_btn.removeClass('fa-thumbs-o-up');
                $clicked_btn.addClass('fa-thumbs-up');
            } else if (act == 'unlike') {
                $clicked_btn.removeClass('fa-thumbs-up');
                $clicked_btn.addClass('fa-thumbs-o-up');
            }
            // alert(res.likes);
    }

    });
});
});
```

db.php:

```
<?php  
session_start();
// $email = "$_SESSION['email']";

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','commentsection');
echo "working?";
// $user_id = 1;

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}




if (isset($_POST['key'])) {
    echo "isset working?";
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch ($action) {
        case 'like':
            console.log($email);
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO rating (uid, rating, user_id) VALUES ($post_id, 'like', $email) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rating='like'";
            break;
        case 'dislike':
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO rating (uid, rating, user_id) VALUES ($post_id, 'dislike', $email ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rating='dislike'";
            break;
        case 'unlike':
            $sql2 = "DELETE FROM rating WHERE uid=$post_id AND r_uid=0";
            break;
        case 'undislike':
            $sql2 = "DELETE FROM rating WHERE uid=$post_id AND r_uid=0";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    echo getRating($post_id);
    // exit(0);


}

?>
```

I tried with `isset($_POST['key'])` then `isset($_POST['action'])` and `isset($_POST['post_id'])` but it didn't work, the function is not executing; it may return false over the condition.

I did most of the things found on Google but none of them worked.
I really don't have much knowledge about this. So please be nice and help me, been stuck on this for a week.

Comment: What happens with this code? This is open to SQL injections, and the `$email` usage in the query seems to be invalid (strings need to be quoted). You also could simplify this greatly, `case 'unlike': case 'undislike':` and make the `rating` a variable with ternary then only need one insert as well

Comment: I got no problem in $email, it displays my id after I logged in; About the case, I will change it afterward but the function is not executing at all

Comment: You have a JS `console.log()` mixed in the PHP code, which is likely causing a runtime error. If you do not have PHP error reporting enabled, this will appear as though it is not executing completely. Always when developing and testing code, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your code.

Comment: I didn't mix the js with php bro, just used console.log to ensure whether it is running or not. I added the 2 lines u provided and also saw the console by inspecting and got no errors.

Comment: Dump the $_POST variable and see what exactly is in there....print_r($_POST)...

Comment: Array 
(
 [key] => 1
 [action] => like
 [post_id] => 101
)
just as i want which is displayed over script file
but db.php shows Array ()